# comparision between list and tuple/list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to compare list element with tuple and if it matches i want to print that whole line from a tuple.

**like:**

```
    a = [('rose', ' L2   Gi    10   UP    95    00'), 
         ('marri',' L2   Gi    10   UP    82    00'), 
         ('lily', ' L2   Gi    10   UP    88    02'), 
         ('dafo', ' L2   Te    10   UP    99    00'), 
         ('sunflower', '101')]

    b = {'lily', 'rose'}
```

if `'lily'` of b matches with `'lily'` of a then i want print whole line of a which contains `'lily'`.

**For example**

```
'lily', ' L2   Gi    10  UP    88    02'

'rose', ' L2   Gi    10  UP    95    00'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for entry in a:
    if entry[0] in b:
        print(entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner version of Anna's answer

```
values = [x for bb in b for x in a if x[0] == bb]
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have missed stg, but would this work ?

```html
for i in b:
    print(i, dict(a)[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
for bb in b:
    values = [x for x in a if x[0] == bb]
    print(values)
```

which gives you

```
[('lily', ' L2 Gi 10 UP 88 02')]
[('rose', ' L2 Gi 10 UP 95 00')]
```

full code:

```
a = [('rose', ' L2   Gi    10   UP    95    00'),  ('marri',' L2   Gi    10   UP    82    00'), ('lily', ' L2   Gi    10   UP    88    02'), ('dafo', ' L2   Te    10   UP    99    00'), ('sunflower', '101')]

b = ['lily', 'rose']

for bb in b:
    values = [x for x in a if x[0] == bb]
    print(values)
```

Comment: sorry but it is giving empty list :-(

Comment: swap b = {'lily', 'rose'} to b = ['lily', 'rose']

Comment: @sonali I added the full code that I ran on my terminal, can you copy and paste and see if that works for you? you may have a formatting issue.

Comment: if b = {'lily', 'rose'} like this will that code work for this too.

Comment: @sonali I just tried and it worked on mine, but that's not the proper way to write a list.. you use '{ }' to declare dictionaries and '[ ]' for lists.

Comment: @sonali glad to hear it and no worries! Just make sure you mark the question as answered